# How to read model's schema and validate in postman test script

Tags: postman, postman-collection-runner, postman-pre-request-script, postman-testcase

I have a model schema and i want to read those and validate in postman test script.
could you please share your suggestions ?

Comment: What's does the response body look like? What schema do you have so far? Have you looked at using `pm.response.to.have.jsonSchema(your schema)` in the test?

Comment: And why is this related to node.js ?

Comment: @AbhishekRanjan i will take care of tags from next time. Thanks :)

Comment: @DannyDainton Is there any way to read model schema instead of putting schema into test section of postman?

Comment: Could be read from a variable value or one of the test script at Request/Folder/Collection level but that's it in the UI - If you're using Newman, it _could_ be read from an external file.